# Peewee and raw SQL create statements

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, peewee

We have a dedicated Postgres database for each client, since we can't handle database migrations for each one without going crazy, we're using raw SQL files. We have one initial SQL file that creates the tables and inserts some data. The problem comes after we try to insert into a table which was previously populated with the initial SQL script using `INSERT INTO` sentences.

Somehow, peewee wants to create the new record using ID=1 thus raising an `IntegrityrError` (we created a bunch from the SQL file). I'm not really sure how to handle this scenario.

I have a base model:

```
class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    active = peewee.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_at = peewee.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        database = database
```

An example model that uses the `BaseModel`:

```
class UserRole(BaseModel):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User)
    role = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Role)

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('user', 'role'), True),
        )
```

Say `UserRole` has five records from the initial SQL script. If a try to create a new record using `UserRole.create` from the flask app, then I get an integrity error compalining about the ID=1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am sure I cannot answer this. But it might help future visitors to actually have the code for 1.The full UserRole.create command that you are using, which is causing the error and 2. The actuall error mesage and maybe a gist link to the stack trace as well as 3. What are you passing to the UserRole.create and what are the "types" of these values you are passing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting a new data, you need to fix sequences that provides you id values. [Here](https://gist.github.com/henriquemenezes/962829815e8e7875f5f4376133b2f209) is an example how to do that. After you do that, try to avoid explicit ids in your insert queries, allow db assign id value for you

Comment: You'll also want to make sure the primary-key sequences are owned by the correct user.

Comment: Thanks! I had to run `setval()` with the last ID after each insert from the SQL file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the database, the tables do not correctly refer to auto_increment'ing sequences. For example, if the table has a column 'id' which has a default value of the next value of a sequence, is the sequence set to the right value. Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE user ALTER user_id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('user_id_seq');
select max(id) from user; -- returns 21
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 22, true);
```

Comment: Yeah, `setval()` was the solution. Thanks!